# Poor electrical load forecasts from auto.arima, why?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have 4 years electrical load data. I split the data into 3 years (75%) training data, 1 year for testing (25%). Also I have the temperature data for each day during the previous period. (The link to the dataset: [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B08HdcWBksWcTUxqc1ByOW1UVEU).)

I want to make use of the temperature data to enhance the forecasting using argument `xreg` in `arima` function.

Here is my code:

```
mydata1<-read.csv("1st pape/kaggle_data.csv");
mydata<-ts(mydata1[,2],start = c(2004),frequency = 365)

#split the data into trainData and test data
trainData = window(mydata, end=c(2007))
testData = window(mydata, start=c(2007))
temp<-ts(mydata1[,3],start = c(2004),frequency = 365)

#split the temperature into trainData and test data
trainReg = window(temp, end=c(2007))
testReg = window(temp, start=c(2007))
```

Apply ARIMA model without using `xreg`:

```
mod_arima <- auto.arima(trainData, ic='aicc', stepwise=FALSE)
summary(mod_arima)
Series: trainData 
ARIMA(1,0,3) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1      ma1      ma2      ma3  intercept
      0.9642  -0.2098  -0.2157  -0.1693  24008.122
s.e.  0.0110   0.0322   0.0330   0.0325   1018.007

sigma^2 estimated as 9318421:  log likelihood=-10347.38
AIC=20706.75   AICc=20706.83   BIC=20736.75

Training set error measures:
                   ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE
Training set 6.102332 3045.638 2293.946 -1.519484 9.625694 0.5151126
                    ACF1
Training set 0.004483007

plot(forecast(mod_arima)); lines(testData , col="red", start= c(2007,1,1)); 
legend("topleft", lty=1,col=c(4,2),legend=c("forecasted data","real data"))

y <- msts(trainData, c(7,365)) # multiseasonal ts
x <- msts(trainReg, c(7,365)) # multiseasonal ts

fit <- auto.arima(y, xreg=(fourier(y, K=c(3,30))))
fit_f <- forecast(fit, xreg= fourier(y, K=c(3,30), 365), 365)
plot(fit_f)
```

the red line is the actual data, while the blue is the foretasted data. The left plot is appeared before using fourier function, while the right after using it.

[image]

Apply ARIMA model using `xreg`:

```
mod_arima2 <- auto.arima(trainData ,xreg = trainReg, ic='aicc', stepwise=FALSE)
summary(mod_arima2)
Series: trainData 
ARIMA(1,0,3) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1      ma1      ma2      ma3  intercept  trainReg
      0.9709  -0.2403  -0.2108  -0.1609  29984.188  -88.3976
s.e.  0.0094   0.0320   0.0330   0.0321   1468.108   13.1966

sigma^2 estimated as 8955023:  log likelihood=-10325.13
AIC=20664.26   AICc=20664.36   BIC=20699.26

Training set error measures:
                   ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE
Training set 6.030471 2984.292 2267.803 -1.464553 9.529988 0.5092422
                    ACF1
Training set 0.005526977

plot(forecast(mod_arima2,xreg = testReg)); lines(testData , col="red", start= c(2007,1,1)); 
legend("topleft", lty=1,col=c(4,2), legend=c("forecasted data","real data"))

l = (fourier(y, K=c(3,30)))
z = cbind(l,x)
fit2 <- auto.arima(y, xreg=z)
fit_f2 <- forecast(fit, xreg= z, 365)
plot(fit_f2)
```

[image]
**Questions**:

1. Did I use `xreg` correctly?
2. If yes, why is the summary the same without using `xreg`?
3. Why are the forecasts far away from the real data?

Comment: There is a lot going on in your post, I am having trouble to follow. Could you please try making it a little bit more structural and highlight what the actual questions are?

Comment: thank you for your replay, I highlighted the question and edit the post again.

Comment: Can you include the model output when you use `xreg` and also when you do not use `xreg`? Because now you only have one graph which does not illustrate the two cases you mention. By the way, which model does the graph correspond to? The model in the last line of the code?

Comment: I updated the post again as you mentioned. the model in the last line is related to using xreg in forecasting.

Comment: Currently it seems that you are not capturing seasonality properly. You could try adding Fourier terms in both cases (without and with temperature data). Also, the ARMA coefficients hardly get affected by the inclusion of the temperature data. I wonder why...

Comment: I read proff Rob J Hyndman article about using Fourier.  I already tried before ,but the result was poor. I will update the post after using it now.
fit <- auto.arima(trainData, xreg=(fourier(trainData, K=c(3,30))))